# Using arma::solve with RcppParallel: how to avoid stack imbalance?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I want to use arma::solve within a rcppParallel worker.
The problem is that the code results in a crash of R, probably due to stack imbalance.

To avoid stack imbalance issues one should use RMatrix objects instead of arma::mat objects in the worker as far as I understand the decription of the rcppParallel package.
However arma::solve only accepts arma::mat objects.

How is this done correctly? What is the correct way to deal with this issue?

Thank you very much for any suggestions/help/corrections!

Below you find my approach which unfortunately easily results in crash of R (especially when executed serveral times):

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;


struct MakeITER : public Worker {
  // input matrix to read from
  const arma::mat MAT;
  const arma::colvec VEC;
  const int p;
   // output matrix to write to
  arma::mat res1;

  MakeITER( arma::mat res, const arma::mat MAT0, 
  const arma::colvec VEC0, int p0)
  :  res1(res), MAT(MAT0), VEC(VEC0), p(p0){
    res1.zeros();
  }

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    int j, m;   

    arma::colvec coef(p);

    for(m = begin; m < end; m++){              
      try{
            coef = arma::solve(MAT, VEC);
            for(j=0; j<p; j++) {
                    res1(j,m) = coef[j];
            } ;
      }catch(...){             
            for(j=0; j<p; j++) {
              res1(j,m) =  arma::datum::nan; 
            };
        }   
    }    
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat fuc( arma::mat MAT0,  arma::colvec VEC0, int nmkt, int p0) {
  // result:
  arma::mat res(p0,nmkt);  

  MakeITER makeit(res, MAT0,  VEC0, p0);
  parallelFor(0, nmkt, makeit);

  return(  res );

};
```

In R:

```
# setup:
p1   = 5  # dimension of matrix to solve
nrep1= 70 # number of repetitions
set.seed(123)
MAT0 =  matrix(rnorm(p1^2)/10,p1,p1)
VEC0 =  matrix(rnorm(p1)/10,p1,1)

# Runs okay:
for(i in 1:10){
  r1=fuc(MAT0, VEC0, nrep1, p1)  ;str(r1)
}


# Results in crash of R (especially when executed serveral times):
for(i in 1:10){
  r1=fuc(MAT0*0, VEC0, nrep1, p1)  ;str(r1)
}
```

In Rstudio (R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31, Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit))
I typically receive a message like this:

```
Warning: stack imbalance in '.Call', 35 then 33
Warning: stack imbalance in '=', 29 then 27
Warning: stack imbalance in '{', 26 then 24
```

and then:

```
Error: Unable to establish connection with R session
```

and there is a fatal error.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel -- the code in the current post uses RMatrix in the worker, so the relevance of the previous answer is not clear?

Comment: Running this code just gives me a segfault (Error: C stack usage  140730378409876 is too close to the limit) so I think there is something else more fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: I think it's the error messages printed by `arma_bad("solve(): solution not found");`, or at least adding `CXXFLAGS=-DARMA_DONT_PRINT_ERRORS` to ~/.R/Makevars succeeds. I don't know what the Rcpp best practices would be in this case...

Comment: @MartinMorgan There are Armadillo objects 'inside' which are (these days) proxy R objects.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes, the question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523979/stack-imbalance-with-rcppparallel
However the problem still occured in the example when I tried to adjust the code to the solution from this post 
(I changed the question now to make the approach more similar to the solution from the mentioned post.). 
Therefore, my question seemed for me to be no dublicate.
Thank you very much for your valuable hint that "There are Armadillo objects 'inside' which are (these days) proxy R objects."

Comment: @MartinMorgan Great! Adding the line:" PKG_CXXFLAGS=-DARMA_DONT_PRINT_ERRORS " to the "Makevars" file in the folder "src" of the 'R package' under developement also works for me. For me this is a good solution and I would be happy to accept it as answer to the question, if you would like to repost. I could not have found out this on my own. Thanks a lot!