# R encountered a fatal error while running a parallel program

Tags: parallel-processing, rcpp

I have a function name `markovchainListRcpp` which takes two argument one is `list` and another is `number of sequences` we want.

Let's see with an example

```
> mclist
[[1]]
Unnamed Markov chain 
 A  3 - dimensional discrete Markov Chain with following states: 
 a, b, c 
 The transition matrix   (by rows)  is defined as follows: 
    a   b   c
a 0.2 0.5 0.3
b 0.0 0.2 0.8
c 0.1 0.8 0.1


[[2]]
Unnamed Markov chain 
 A  3 - dimensional discrete Markov Chain with following states: 
 a, b, c 
 The transition matrix   (by rows)  is defined as follows: 
    a   b   c
a 0.2 0.5 0.3
b 0.0 0.2 0.8
c 0.1 0.8 0.1


[[3]]
Unnamed Markov chain 
 A  3 - dimensional discrete Markov Chain with following states: 
 a, b, c 
 The transition matrix   (by rows)  is defined as follows: 
    a   b   c
a 0.2 0.5 0.3
b 0.0 0.2 0.8
c 0.1 0.8 0.1
```

See the output of `markovchainListRcpp`

```
> markovchainListRcpp(n = 2, object = mclist)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2

[[2]]
[1] "b" "c" "c" "a" "b" "b"
```

we get two sequence:

```
"b" "c" "c" (1)
"a" "b" "b" (2)
```

These sequence are independent of each other. So I want to generate these sequences in parallel using `RcppParallel`.

Below is my `RCppParallel` implementation to generate n sequences in parallel

```
struct SequenceMC : public Worker
{   
  // source
  const List tmatList;
  const int num_tmat;

  // store results
  List output;

  // constructors
  SequenceMC(const List tmat, const int n) : tmatList(tmat), num_tmat(n), output() {}
  SequenceMC(SequenceMC &sequenceMC, Split) : tmatList(sequenceMC.tmatList), num_tmat(sequenceMC.num_tmat), output(){}

  // process just the elements of the range I've been asked to
  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    List temp;
    CharacterVector helper;
    int n = end-begin;
    int m = num_tmat;

    temp = markovchainListRcpp(n, tmatList, false); 
    helper = temp[1];

    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
      CharacterVector help(num_tmat);
      for(int j = 0;j < m;j++) {
        help[j] = helper[m*i+j];
      }  
      output.push_back(help);
    }
  }

  void join(SequenceMC& rhs) { 
    List temp = rhs.output;
    for(int i = 0;i < temp.size();i++) {
      output.push_back(temp[i]);
    }
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List markovchainSequenceParallelRcpp(List object, int n) {

  List tmatList = object;

  SequenceMC sequenceMC(tmatList, tmatList.size());

  // call it with parallelReduce
  parallelReduce(0, n, sequenceMC);

  return sequenceMC.output;
}
```

See What happens When I call parallel function.

```
> markovchainSequenceParallelRcpp(mclist, 5)
[[1]]
[1] "b" "c" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "c" "c"

[[3]]
[1] "b" "c" "b"

[[4]]
[1] "b" "c" "c"

[[5]]
[1] "b" "c" "c"
```

I got the result.

```
> markovchainSequenceParallelRcpp(mclist, 15)
```

This time RStudio crashes **R Session Aborted**.
But sometime it crashes for `n = 5` and sometime it does not crash for even `n = 20.` I am not getting What is going on. Any idea.

**Please see what I observed today.**

```
> markovchainSequenceParallelRcpp(mclist, 1)
[[1]]
[1] "b" "c" "c"

> markovchainSequenceParallelRcpp(mclist, 2)
[[1]]
[1] "b" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "c" "c"

> markovchainSequenceParallelRcpp(mclist, 3)
[[1]]
[1] "b" "c" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "c" "b" "b"

[[3]]
[1] "b" "b" "c"

> markovchainSequenceParallelRcpp(mclist, 4)
Error in markovchainSequenceParallelRcpp(mclist, 4) : 
  STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'pairlist'
```

Still unable to solve the problem. Please suggest any way to overcome this problem. I am working on it for the last one week. Now it seem to be wastage of time. Please help.

Comment: RStudio uses mult-ithreading for its UI components; there are known cases of interactions.  Run your code outside of it.

Comment: It means that problem is not because of List, CharacterVector etc